# Decrypt a string encrypted by the EncryptSymmetric() AMPscript function using PHP

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, php, encryption

I read elsewhere in StackExchange that it's not possible to decrypt AES strings originating from AMPScript in PHP. Is this true? It seems that it should be possible with mcrypt.

Also, part two for this question... if AES isn't possible, then should we go with DES or TripleDES? We need to be able to decrypt data generated in ExactTarget's EncryptSymmetric() function in a clients's PHP environment.

Comment: This is on topic as it pertains to ExactTarget.

Comment: @those who vote to close, can you at least leave a comment ?

Comment: any luck with this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and thanks to the great work of @Kolohe with the mcrypt example I found a solution with openssl_decrypt and DES encryption.

With the upgrade to php7 we replaced mcrypt with openssl. So mcrypt wasn't a solution for us.

Because we pass the encrypted string as GET parameter it is wrapped with base64.

That's the AMPScript:

```
%%[
set @email = 'gone@world.com'
set @email_code = Base64Encode(EncryptSymmetric(@email, "des;mode=ecb;padding=zeros", @null, 'ab12cd34'))
Output(Concat(@email, '<br>'))
Output(Concat(@email_code, '<br>'))
]%%
```

That's the result from the AMPScript:

```
gone@world.com
TklMUTk4UjBhVlRWeXdDWHJCYk92Zz09
```

That's the PHP part:

```
$crypted = 'TklMUTk4UjBhVlRWeXdDWHJCYk92Zz09';
$crypted = base64_decode($crypted);
var_dump($crypted);
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($crypted, 'des-ecb', 'ab12cd34', OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, '');
var_dump($decrypted);
$decrypted = trim($decrypted);
var_dump($decrypted);
```

And the PHP result:

```
string(24) "NILQ98R0aVTVywCXrBbOvg=="
string(16) "gone@world.com"
string(14) "gone@world.com"
```

The decrypted string has 2 control charactes at the end. I don't know why and in the end I wrapped it with a trim to solve the problem. It seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work with DES 
Still working on AES.

Use the example on the documentation for DES
https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/encryption/EncryptSymmetric.html

Then use functions like like these

```
function decryptEtDES($key,$string)
{
    $string = base64_decode(str_replace(' ', "+", $string));
    $rtn = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $rtn = rtrim($rtn, "\0\4");
    return($rtn);
}

function encryptEtDES($key,$string)
{
    $rtn = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $rtn = base64_encode($rtn);
    return($rtn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each individual algorithm is slightly unique between programming language, and ExactTarget's is based on C#.

In order to use PHP, you would need to recreate the algorithm  that C# uses in PHP.

The simplest way to overcome this would be to create a landing page that uses AMPscript and pass the data to the page to be encrypted/decrypted.

Comment: Thanks Kelly. What about just using DES instead, though? It's early enough in the process that we could try something like that.

Comment: I've not gotten it to work in any method, but this makes me want to attempt again just to make sure.

Comment: This page seems to give me some hope, but not able to reproduce from exact target yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130989/php-decrypt-a-string-from-c-sharp-net-rijndael-256

Comment: @KellyJAndrews were you able to create a PHP script to decrypt C#'s encryption from ExactTarget's side?

Comment: @dchayka not successfully, no